# How to prevent system to generate log file

Tags: kernel, hard-drive, log

My Question is little bit surprising, but i need it. I am using a slow processor laptop, now i found that HDD has some bad sectors and HDD response becomes slow. But disk health is ok(according to smart tools). I can not change my HDD right now. So decide to reduce disk operation. How do i prevent system to generate log file or any other file which are used to keep history? I know LOG file is very important but i don't care it right now. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get what you're after by moving the log location to tmpfs, which will not be written to disk (unless swapped).

Edit the files under /etc/rsyslog.d/* and make sure they're pointing to /tmp/filename instead of /var/log/filename.

Note: this is a hack.